# Changing values of multi dimentional arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the results of a mysql query in a multi dimentional array as follows:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => john doe [id] => john@doe.com [userlevel] => 1 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => mary jane [id] => mary@jane.com [userlevel] => 5 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => joe blow [id] => joe@blow.com [userlevel] => 1 )
);
```

I would like to loop through these, check the value of the [userlevel] value and if == '5', then modify the [name] value. The idea is to give a visual indicator next to those users that are a certain userlevel.

I've tried to loop through using foreach, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What have you tried? Something like this should work.

```
foreach ($result as $i => $item)
{
    if ($item->userlevel == 5)
        $result[$i]->name = 'modified name';
}
```

Comment: @LucM: How can you tell? OP mentions trying looping with foreach, but there's no code for us to see. This snippet works just fine in [my tests](http://codepad.org/97gp2gKs).

Comment: I took your code defining `$result = array()` and `$result[ 'a' ] = array( 'name' => 'Hello', 'userlevel' => 5 );` and it doesn't work...

Comment: @LucM: Yes, but in the question the array contains objects (`stdClass Object`), not arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($array as $i => &$user) {
    if ($user->userlevel == 5) {
        $user->name = 'foo';
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The ampersand `&` is very important here.

Alternatively:

```
for ($i = 0, $arrayLen = count($array); $i < $arrayLen; ++$i) {
    if ($array[$i]->userlevel == 5) {
        $array[$i]->name = 'foo';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[From PHP documentation site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

`Unless the array is referenced, foreach operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. foreach has some side effects on the array pointer. Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the foreach without resetting it.`